# How do I access groupList.i in a django for loop?

Tags: html, django, for-loop

I have created a for loop in django inside a template. I have a list of names that is declared as `groupList = ['superUsers', 'group1', 'group2', 'groupless']`. I can call individual members of the group by saying `{{ groupList.2 }}` (this outputs group2). But as soon as I try to call `{{ groupList.i }}` inside my for loop, there is no output. My code looks like this:

```
{% for i in length|get_range %}
    {{ groupList.i }} <br /> <br />
    {% for staff in staffList.i %}
        {{staff}} <br /> <br />
    {% endfor  %}
{% endfor %}
```

Length is defined as: `length = len(groupList)`.

I hope to be able to have the first grouplist name to show up followed by a list of names, followed by the second groupList name then it's corresponding list of  names. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try defining another template variable as:

```
foo = zip(groupList, staffList)
```

and using it:

```
{% for group, staff in foo %}
    {{ group }}
    {{ staff }}
{% endfor %}
```

Seems like the most elegant way of doing what you want (imho.)

Comment: You're right. This is exactly what I want. I implemented:
{% for group, staff in foo %}
    {{ group }}
    {% for name in staff %}
    {{ name }}
{% endfor %}
And it worked perfectly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try something similar to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11784863/456848)

Here's how I would change it to fit your needs:

```
{% for i in length|get_range %}
    {% with i as index %}
    {% with i|slugify|add:":"|add:i as subset %}
    {% with staffList|slice:subset as sublist %}

    <p>Previous item: {{ sublist.0 }}</p>

    {% endwith %}
    {% endwith %}
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

So this is definitely NOT an elegant solution, but this is how I perform a set/list `.` lookup  when I want to use a computed value.

In reality, aviraldg's solution is much more elegant and uses a better approach for what you'd like to specifically accomplish.