# Django template for loop. Member before

Tags: django, templates, for-loop

I want to create such loop:

```
{% for object in objects %}
    {% if object.before != object %}
         {{ object }} this is different
    {% else %}
        {{ object }} this is the same
{% endfor %}
```

Based on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#for I can't. Is there really no simple way to do this? Or I just need to use counter and check for `objects[counter-1]`?

P.S. `.before` is theoretical and objects is simple query list. I want to take and do something with the loop member that encountered before current loop member.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check [ifchanged](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#ifchanged) template tag

Comment: This directly solves my problem +1, yet it does not answer question I raised - "I want to take and do something with the loop member that encountered before current loop member"

Comment: Use custom template tag to remember last object e.g. http://www.soyoucode.com/2011/set-variable-django-template

Answer (score 0):

There is a "simple way" to do this: write a custom template tag. They're really not hard. This would probably do the trick (untested):

```
@register.simple_tag
def compare_objects(object_list):
    comparisons = []
    for i in range(1, len(object_list)):
        if object_list[i] > object_list[i-1]:
            comparisons.append('bigger')
        else:
            comparisons.append('smaller')
    return comparisons
```

Comment: I'm searching for template solution if possible. If I will not found any other way to solve this, this is obvious way.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in template tags and filters don't make it easy (as of Django 1.4), but it is possible by using the `with` tag to cache variables and the `add`, `slugify`, and `slice` filters to generate a new list with only one member.

The following example creates a new list whose sole member is the previous member of the `forloop`:

```
{% for item in list %}
    {% if not forloop.first %}
        {% with forloop.counter0|add:"-1" as previous %}
        {% with previous|slugify|add:":"|add:previous as subset %}
        {% with list|slice:subset as sublist %}

        <p>Current item: {{ item }}</p>
        <p>Previous item: {{ sublist.0 }}</p>

        {% endwith %}
        {% endwith %}
        {% endwith %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This isn't an elegant solution, but the django template system has two faults that make this hack unavoidable for those who don't what to write custom tags:

1. Django template syntax does not allow nested curly parenthesis. Otherwise, we could do this:

   ```
       {{ list.{{ forloop.counter|add:-1  }} }}
   ```
2. The lookup operator does not accept values stored using `with` (and perhaps for good reason)

   ```
       {% with forloop.counter|add:-1 as index %}
           {{ list.index }}
       {% endwith %}
   ```

Answer (score -2):

This code should work just fine as a django template, as long as `object` has a property or no-argument method called `before`, and `objects` is iterable (and '<' is defined).

```
{% for object in objects %}
    {% if object.before < object %}
        this is bigger
    {% else %}
        this is smaller
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Clearly I was misunderstood. Updated the question.