# How to annotate the result of a model method to a django queryset

Tags: python, django, django-annotate

From the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) on `annotate()`:

> Annotates each object in the QuerySet with the provided list of query
>   expressions. An expression may be a simple value, **a reference to a
>   field on the model** (or any related models), or...

Is it possible to annotate the results of a method for the model?

I've tried like this:

`my_queryset.annotate(ann=my_method(request.user))`

and

`my_queryset.annotate(my_method(request.user))`

But I get an error that `my_method` is not defined.  The method exists and works fine normally: `object.my_method(request.user)`

I think there is a decorator to have a method treated like a field, but I can't seem to find any info on that (it might have been for django template based method calls, so possibly not related)

An alternate solution is provided in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32683954/how-to-add-some-context-to-each-entry-of-a-django-queryset).  But I would like to know if it is possible to `annotate` method results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django custom annotation function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30416270/django-custom-annotation-function)

Answer (score 1):

This question is very old but I want to answer it, as it may be helpful for someone like me searching for the answers
basically, I tried a lot of ways to do it, but there is no direct way to do it, the workaround I figured out is after making the initial basic query like  
my_queryset = myModelClass.objects.annotate(ann = Value(False, output_field = models.BooleanField() )).all()

/# added an extra field filled with default value, then looped through the /# returned query set and call the model method like below

for record in my_queryset : 
record.ann = cqa.my_method(request.user)

Thank you